# Ubuntu often warn me about low space left on `/home`

Tags: 20.04, mount, disk-usage

I have partitions (located on different disk) mounted as `/home/USER` folder. Ubuntu often warn me about low space left on `/home`.

Is there a way to prevent Ubuntu count these external mounted directory as space taken on `/home` ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using a supported release of Ubuntu? Which? Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting and [edit] your question, don't reply via Add comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Gnome-based distribution, then you can exclude specific directories from the low-storage notification via `dconf-editor`. Here's how:

1. Open dconf Editor:
   [image: Open dconf Editor]
2. Search for `housekeeping` and double-click "Ignore Paths":
   [image: dconf Editor - Ignore Paths]
3. Add the directories you wish to exclude from the space calculation by adding them to the text box:
   [image: dconf Editor - Path Entry]
   <sub>**Note:** Be sure to use the full path and wrap it in a single quote. This needs to be written as an array of strings.</sub>
4. Press "Apply" and close dconf Editor

Be careful not to exclude your entire home directory, as a full disk may prevent you from logging in.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have any `housekeeping` entry in mu Ubuntu 20.04 https://i.imgur.com/wkw8ct5.png